# manipulating json data and simple for statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

If I'm getting some data as an array

```
var data =  {"answer":"OK","data":[["Marco","123"],["John","44245"],["Wayne","645464"]]}
```

how can I inside loop iterate trough them and print inside console this coresponding values

```
Marco 123
John  44254, ..

Marco - 123
John - 44245, ...
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is a key of data object.You need to first retrieve the value of `data.data` which will return an array. Now loop through each of these array elements to get the values.

```
var data =  {"answer":"OK",
        "data":[["Marco","123"],["John","44245"],["Wayne","645464"]]
        }

var getData = data.data; //data key is an array

getData.forEach(function(item){
      item.forEach(function(innerItem){
       console.log(innerItem)
   })
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/18n7e9k0/)

Answer (score 3):

```
data.data.forEach(array => {
    console.log(`${array[0]} - ${array[1]}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   console.log(data[i]);
}
```

This feels too simple, am I missing part of the question?

Update:

It was too simple...

Just to make sure my answer is actually correct, to get just the values of the data inside of data, you need to do:

```
var data = {"answer":"OK","data":[["Marco","123"],["John","44245"],"Wayne","645464"]]};
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
   console.log(data.data[i][1]);
}
```

But, @user2181397 gave a better answer.

Comment: possibly data.data

Comment: `data.data[0] = ["Marco","123"]` so you have to use `data.data[i][0]` and `data.data[i][1]`

Comment: You're right. I like @user2181397's answer better anyway.